# After installing a package in VS, how can I go to the docs for that package?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

After I install a package from NuGet, what's the easiest way to open up the docs or help files for that specific package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to get detailed information / documentation about a nuget package is the  "ProjectUrl" that is contained in the nuspec. The Visual Studio Nuget add-in shows it as "Project Information" and the nuget.org gallery shows it as "Project site". In fact, many packages just contain an assembly and nothing else. So maybe Visual Studio's Object Browser is the fastest way for a quick overview.